# AS2 Remove the Last 11 Characters from a Variable ActionScript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

How do I go about removing the last 11 characters from a variable in ActionScript 2?  I'm trying to delete the last 11 characters from a variable that contains a date from a twitter XML feed so that the variable goes from "Tue Jun 07 03:15:15 +0000 2011" to "Tue Jun 07 03:15:15"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **substr** method of the String object:

```
var dateString:String="Tue Jun 07 03:15:15 +0000 2011";
var resultString:String=dateString.substr(0, dateString.length-11);
trace(resultString);
```